# Pandas itertuples are not named tuples as expected?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-collections

Using this page from the Pandas documentation, I wanted to read a CSV into a dataframe, and then turn that dataframe into a list of named tuples.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html?highlight=itertuples

I ran the code below...

```
import pandas as pd

def csv_to_tup_list(filename):
    myfile = filename
    df = pd.read_csv(myfile,sep=',')
    df.columns = ["term", "code"]
    tup_list = []
    for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name="Synonym"):
         tup_list.append(row)
    return (tup_list)

test = csv_to_tup_list("test.csv")
type(test[0])
```

... and the type returned is `pandas.core.frame.Synonym`, not named tuple. Is this how it is supposed to work, or am I doing something wrong?

My CSV data is just two columns of data:

```
a,1
b,2
c,3
```

for example.

Comment: What version of pandas are you on? You are linking to an older version of the documentation than the current version: 0.22.0 release date 2017-12-29.

Comment: 0.22.0 - I linked to the wrong documentation, but it hasn't changed. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Named tuple" is not a type. `namedtuple` is a type *factory*. `pandas.core.frame.Synonym` is the type it created for this call, using the name *you* picked:

```
for row in df.itertuples(index=False, name="Synonym"):
#                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is expected behavior.